# How to return Objects from Repository as Json on Symfony3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to send repository object as json
my controller code:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){   
        $data = $request->request->get('id');
        $bedroom = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$data));

        $this->container->get('logger')->addInfo('somesh');

        return $json = new Response(json_encode(array('bedroom' => $bedroom)));   
       }
```

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
     var id_select = $('#bedroom_view_bedroom').val();        
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: '{{ (path('listingview', {'id': id})) }}',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: {id:id_select}, 
        success: function(result,status,xhr){
           var inst_arr = JSON.parse(result);
           console.log(inst_arr);
          },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {     
                console.log(status);
            } 
        }); 
  });
```

here i am getting empty object as a response. how can i send repository object as json using symfony3. help me any one. Thanks in advance...

Edit:

I dont know where it is going wrong i tried below code like

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $data = $request->request->get('id');
        $bedroom = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id' => $data));
        if (null === $bedroom) {
            $bedroomJson = '';
        }
        $this->container->get('logger')->addInfo('somesh');  
        $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');           
        $bedroomJson = $serializer->serialize($bedroom, 'json');

        return new Response($bedroomJson, Response::HTTP_OK, ['content-type' => 'application/json']);
    }
```

console it showing

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/epitahousing/web/app_dev.php/provider/listing/view/8 500 (Internal Server Error)error
```

if i try to find repository object before xmlHttpRequest like

```
$bedroom = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id' => '12'));
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {           
      //code
    }
```

here showing proper object but i really don't know json whats going wrong

Edit2:

```
$bedroom = $this->em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$data));

        $output['rentamount'] = $bedroom->getRentamount();
        $output['rentcurrency'] = $bedroom->getRentcurrency()->getValue();
        $output['rentduration'] = $bedroom->getRentduration()->getValue();
        $output['bondamount'] = $bedroom->getBondamount();
        $output['bondcurrency'] = $bedroom->getBondcurrency()->getValue();
        $output['leaseminduration'] = $bedroom->getLeaseminduration()->getValue();
        $output['leasemaxduration'] = $bedroom->getLeasemaxduration()->getValue();
return $json = new Response(json_encode($output));
```

I done like this now it's working fine...
Thanks for every one... such a valuable response

Comment: Do my answer helped you ? If yes please accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Symfony ships with [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/serializer.html) (Choose your Sf version), which you should use for transforming object to json.

**app/config/config.yml**

Enable the serializer component

```
serializer:
        enabled: true
```

**your controller**

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){   
    $data = $request->request->get('id');
    $bedroom = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$data));
    if(null === $bedroom) {
        // return some error response
    }
    $this->container->get('logger')->addInfo('somesh');
    $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
    $bedroomJson = $serializer->serialize($bedroom, 'json');

    return new Response($bedroomJson, Response::HTTP_OK, ['content-type' => 'application/json']);   
}
```

`$bedroomJson` should be a json string representing your entity object. Let me know if something is wrong :) I hope it's helped !

Comment: Thanks for response i am not getting result object it showing  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I had a typo in the require of the `serializer` service, please retry. If an error occured please link it to your comment :)

Comment: what error are you getting @somesh you could get that error for so many different things and not nec. McSky's answer.

Comment: @somesh are you using `app_dev.php`?

Comment: `jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/epitahousing/web/app_dev.php/provider/listing/view/8 500 (Internal Server Error)` Yes he is

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JsonResponse` class;

`return new JsonResponse(array('bedroom' => $bedroom));`

Comment: i tried JsonResponse class; but i am getting 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: how did you use it? can you see me into comment?

Comment: return $json = new JsonResponse(json_encode(array('bedroom' => $bedroom))); like this

Comment: and i tried return new JsonResponse(array('bedroom' => $bedroom)); like this also but nothing changes

Comment: @somesh If you get a 500 error, check your logs instead of trying just some random code. `JsonResponse(json_encode())` makes no sense.

Comment: @Stephan Yeah i am checking

Answer (score 0):

I am using symfony3, in my case, this is working for me.

```
$obj = "your object";
$data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($obj, 'json');
return new Response($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable response @habibun i done through sending object attributes in an json array